# How to add information to database from gridview?

Tags: c#, database, gridview

I have been trying to add new information to my database from a Windows Form (Gridview). This is the method I came up with (but it doesn't work):

```
private void agregarProducto(string id_producto, string id_proveedor, string id_categoria, string cantidad, string precio_actual, string codigo_barras)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

    using (cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO productos(id_producto, id_proveedor, id_categoria, cantidad, precio_actual, codigo_barras) VALUES (@id_producto, @id_proveedor, @id_categoria, @cantidad, @precio_actual, @codigo_barras)";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_producto", tbId_Prod);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_categoria", tbId_categoria);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_proveedor", tb_Id_proveedor);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", tbCantidad);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precio_actual", tbPrecioActual);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo_barras", tbCod_barras);

        cn.Open();
    }
}
```

This is the event that's is supposedly calling it:

```
private void btAgregarNuevo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    agregarProducto(tbId_Prod.Text, tb_Id_proveedor.Text, tbId_categoria.Text, tbCantidad.Text, tbPrecioActual.Text, tbCod_barras.Text);
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't executed the sql. Do this after you open the connection

```
cmd.ExecuteNoneQuery();
```

Comment: Alright it does insert now but it's showing 0's in the fields. I made a query on MySQL and it's working fine my guess is the conversion or the method.

Comment: @GJenyRamirez. You are passing string types to your method that creates and executes the query. Should have this method accept the correct type (presumably int or long) and do the appropriate conversions in your click event. E.g. `int.Parse(tbId_Prod.Text)`

Answer (score 1):

```
private void agregarProducto(string id_producto, string id_proveedor, string id_categoria, string cantidad, string precio_actual, string codigo_barras)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

    using (cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO productos(id_producto, id_proveedor, id_categoria, cantidad, precio_actual, codigo_barras) VALUES (@id_producto, @id_proveedor, @id_categoria, @cantidad, @precio_actual, @codigo_barras)";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_producto", tbId_Prod);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_categoria", tbId_categoria);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_proveedor", tb_Id_proveedor);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", tbCantidad);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precio_actual", tbPrecioActual);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo_barras", tbCod_barras);

        cn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNoneQuery();//This is the line you are missing

        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright it does insert now but it's showing 0's in the fields. I made a query on MySQL and it's working fine my guess is the conversion or the method.